200 points have been chosen on a circle, all with integer number of degrees. Prove that the points there are at least one...
The question :
$200$ points have been chosen on a circle, all with integer number of degrees. Prove that the points there are at least one pair of antipodes, i.e., the points $180°$ apart.
the solution :

Denote the given set of points $A$ and its generic member $a$. Let $B$ be the set of antipodes of the points in $A$, with $b$ as a generic member.
Assume to the contrary that set $A$ contains no antipodes. This assumptions leaves, for $200$ members of $B$, $160$ available locations. Since all $b$'s are different (as are the $a$'s), some of $b$'s will spill out of the $160$ left-over points, meaning that necessarily $c = b$ for some $c∈A$ and $b∈B$. But, by the definition, $b$ is an antipode of some $a∈A$. It follows that both a and $c$ are members of $A$ and are each other's antipodes.

Can someone explain the solution or give a better one ?

The possible angles are $0$ through $359$.  We pair up the antipodes, $(0,180), (1, 181)$ up to $(179, 359)$ resulting in $180$ pairs.  It is impossible to choose $200$ points without hitting the same pair twice.

The solution sounds pretty clear to me. What is it that you do not understand?

Note:  I assume the $160$ was a typo, intending $180$.

@lulu I think the $160$ was intentional: $A$ and $B$ are disjoint so $B$ must lie in the complement of $A$, which is a set of $360-200=160$ points. But $B$ has $200$ points, which is a problem...

@WillOrrick  Ah, yes.  I see that.  The pairing argument seems clearer though.  At least to me.

There are only $360$ places to place the points. If we try to place the points so that none are placed opposite to them, each point placed removes two possible locations from the circle.
For example, if we place a point at $0^{\circ}$, we cannot place one at $180^{\circ}$. Therefore, we can place at most $180$ points that don't have a point opposite them. The next point placed will have to be placed opposite to one of the previously placed points.

Define a set $A_i=\{i, 180+i\}$ with $1\leq i\leq 180$, then $$A_1, A_2, \ldots, A_{180}$$ contains every point on the the circle with integer degrees. Since we have 200 points there is a set $A_i$ with more than one point.
